# setLastModified not working on an NFS share

Tags: java, nfs, solaris-10, nfsclient

I have an NFS share mounted on one of my Solaris server. The path **/appdata/anp** is mounted from Server A onto Server B. Under the share:

`/appdata/anp`

I have a folder named

`/appdata/anp/factory`

In the above directory I put files which has the data that needs to imported/updated in the database. After importing data in the database I move the file to success/failure directory based on the operation result of the imported data.

`/appdata/anp/factory/success`

`/appdata/anp/factory/failure`

I move the file to either of the above directories and update the last modified time of the file to the current system time using:

`file.setLastModified`

which returns a boolean value. The problem is whenever I am doing this update operation it fails to update the timestamp of that file to the current system time.

Does anyone know what are the the scenarios in which

`file.setLastModified`

returns failure. I have even checked the NFS permissions and everything seems okay to me. Is there anyway to know the cases where **setLastModified** could return failure?

Please help me out I am really pulling my hair on this one!! :(

Comment: For all those who have come to this post and read this, it seems like this API doesn't do well on certain platforms and Operating Systems (which in my case is an NFS mount). Finally, I end up using the Unix "touch" command by spawning a System level Thread from Java!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a Unix file system. In my case it was because unix was truncating the last modified milliseconds and setting the last modified to:

System.currentTimeMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000

It was affecting a test case which was manipulating a file then checking for updates via file.lastModified(). I simply added Thread.sleep(1100) before updating the file in my test case and all was resolved.

Hope that helps the next person.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!! I hope it will help others facing similar problems with this API